# How to remove gaps around div with image?

Tags: html, css, angular

one take col-md-4, second col-md-8, but the second with a picture is not 100% width, there are gaps on the left and right sides, could anyone please advise how to remove gaps and make image full size ? Thanks. Here is screenshot [image: Gaps are red]

```css
.upperDiv{
  height: 100px;
  width: 100%;
  background: red;
  margin-top: 20px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.fixed-content {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  object-fit: cover;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="row upperDiv">
    <div class="col-md-4" style="background: #005AA1;">
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-8">
      <img src="assets/libled.jpg" class="fixed-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bootstrap put that padding for you to better align your content, you can remove it by inserting `p-0` (padding = 0px) class name as I remember

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row upperDiv">
    <div class="col-md-4 p-0" style="background: #005AA1;">
      </div>
    <div class="col-md-8 p-0">
      <img src="assets/libled.jpg" class="fixed-content">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at your HTML, you are using bootstrap's grid system (hinted by the col-md-X classes). The gap you see in your example is caused by the padding applied to the cells of the grid system to create the gutter.

You have two possibilities:

1. You put the picture as a background instead, since padding is part of the element, the picture will cover this space too.
2. You remove the gutter.

1 is pretty self explanatory so I'll go straight to two. You can [read about](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.3/layout/grid/#no-gutters) the `.no-gutter` helper class. It needs to be applied to a row and will effectively remove all gutters for the columns in it. But that means you'll loose the gutter on your left column too. You could also remove the padding with a custom class that sets `padding-left:0 !important;padding-right:0 !important;` This will effectively remove the gutter for the specified column element.

Whatever the option you choose, remember that cols are not meant to be used directly for the styling. They are here to help you create columns in which to put your visual elements. Although I pointed 3 different approaches to your problem, the only "pure" solution is to use the `.no-gutter`. Others might have weird visual impacts such as making the gutter effectively only half wide (since the left col participates in half the gutter too) and will not look right if there are other columns near it.